# Diff tool for plaintext files showing hierarchical structures

Tags: text, tree, diff

I have two plaintext files showing hierarchical structures simply formatted with indents, i.e. level 0 has 0 indent, level 1 has 2-spaces indent, level 2 has 4-spaces indent.

Many of the low-level leaf elements have the same names, and thus the usual `vimdiff` tool has difficulty with it because it is not structurally-aware.

In the example below, `level 1aa` is shown as a difference compared to `leaf2`, which does not make sense in a tree context.

What is a good diff tool to make better sense of hierarchical structures?

[image]